# passport js with GET method

Tags: node.js, express, get, passport.js

I'm trying to confirm users email addresses by sending an activator code to their email address. when user clicked on activator URL (GET method), server  will compare activator code + username and try to handle it.

I'm using GET method like this:

```
router.get('/activator/:username/:activator', function(req, res, next){
        passport.authenticate('activator', function(err, user, info){
            if (err) {console.log('Error info: ', info);}
            else if (!user) {console.log('User not found: ' , info)}
            else {console.log('User activated')}
            res.redirect('/');
        })(req, res, next)
 });
```

And `activator.js` is:

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.use('activator', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'username',
            passwordField: 'activator'
        },
        function(username, password, done) { 
            User.findOne({username: username , activator: password},
                function(err, user){
                    if (err){
                        return done(null, false, 'User not found.');
                    }
                    user.activate = true;
                    user.save(function (err) {
                        if (err) return handleError(err);
                        return done(null, user, 'Persistence Registration successful');
                    });
                });
        })
    );
};
```

But server response is: `{ message: 'Missing credentials'}`
It seems passport js and GET method params has some conflicts.

Am i right? what should i do for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

As I said, problem was for GET method & passport connection.
passport function only read from `req.query` which is only on POST method but GET method is using req.params.

So I changed my application code to :

```
router.get('/activator/:username/:activator', function(req, res, next){
        req.query = req.params; // GET to POST simulator!
        passport.authenticate('activator', function(err, user, info){
            if (err) {console.log('Error info: ', info);}
            else if (!user) {console.log('User not found: ' , info)}
            else {console.log('User activated')}
            res.redirect('/');
        })(req, res, next)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

your Strategy fields are not valid, replace it with `email` and `password` and send same parameters from client side

```
module.exports = function(passport) {

  passport.use('activator', new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
    },
    function(username, password, done) {
      User.findOne({
          username: username,
          activator: password
        },
        function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
            return done(null, false, 'User not found.');
          }
          user.activate = true;
          user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            return done(null, user, 'Persistence Registration successful');
          });
        });
    }));
};
```

Comment: Could that be the real issue? I guess the parameters from URL is not accessible in the passport authentication!

Comment: not working , my params are activator and username not email and password

Comment: @ShriramManoharan I didn't see any where except those fields  also can see their docs https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local